# Is it healthier to be able to put weight on easily or with difficulty?

Tags: weight-loss, weight-gain

Some context:

I find it incredibly easy to gain weight, both muscle and fat. I'm a normal weight, but I keep to a reasonably diet and exercise regularly (squash and weights)

My housemate cannot gain weight to save his life. He's 20kg lighter than me, can pile his face full of food all day everyday without exercising and lose weight. Clearly, we have very different body types and metabolisms.

I've heard people say that being able to put on weight is healthy, but conversely, being overweight is widely regarded as having a negative impact on health and longevity.

**Does scientific literature say anything about which [body type - easy or hard weight gainer] is healthier, which leads to a longer life or which body type is predisposed to certain diseases?**

I've searched for answers but since the internet is full of weight loss tips, most of what I've come across pertains to dieting and fascicle metabolism boosters. Any literature I've found relating to my question is too dense for me to understand in layman's terms.

Comment: I doubt your housemate could do that for *every* meal. In a lot of cases, people who claim they can eat what ever and not gain weight, either have the metabolism to do so (thru higher muscle mass or high activity), or they only eat one large meal per day and hardly anything else, aside from much smaller snacks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking - the less food you consume through your life, the less oxidation happens (metabolic processes use oxygen and it is poisonous in a way). Less risk of cancer, less stress on liver, kidneys and heart. Also low body weight reduces the stress on joints and tissues. Having excessive body weight is correlated with many health risks. I don't have any data, just empirical observations - it's the smaller and lighter people that live longest.

**Body weight and genetics are very important factor, but still just a factor. There are hundreds other lifestyle and environmental factors that determine your long-term health and lifespan.**

Have in mind that light people with fast metabolic rate do not eat all that much as perceived. You need to have a lot of active tissue (muscle), or be extremely active to burn large quantities of calories. Sure, people with high metabolic rate have a slightly higher body temperature, have more energy and are subconsciously more active (have stronger desire to walk and exercise). But there is no magic and the food does not "disappear". Such person might eat a huge amount of food at one meal but "forget" to eat through the next day because they don't have the appetite. In the long run the average total calories consumed per day are just enough to cover the metabolic expense - and that number will be lower for 20kg lighter person, if you have similar activity level. Else they would be storing the extra calories as body weight (fat and/or muscle depending on many things).

Answer (score 0):

It may be the luck of genetic draw, specific genetic makeup helps determine your body weight and how quickly you gain or lose pounds. Researchers studying the human genome have isolated genes that influence fat distribution and development, body mass index and appetite, reports the National Institutes of Health. Genetics play a big rule, however there are other factors such as when you undergo chronic stress or get insufficient sleep, you may gain weight more easily than other people. Stress affects food choices by driving up the desire for unhealthy “comfort foods” like fatty, sugary choices. It may also lead to insomnia, which disturbs the normal function of the hormones leptin and ghrelin, which signal your body when to eat and when to stop. Techniques like yoga, deep breathing, listening to music or reading can help keep your stress levels. Gaining weight easily is definitely healthier